Token Refresh Failure on User Return. Next Auth
I'm working on authentication in a Next.js project using NextAuth version 4.24.4, alongside Next.js version 13.4.10. My goal is to implement a robust token refresh mechanism that works even when users leave the page and return later. While the refresh logic seems to function as expected during an active session, it encounters issues once the user leaves and returns to the webpage.
Here's an overview of the approach I've taken, including the relevant parts of my configuration and the refresh token logic:
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import AuthService from '@/app/service/authService';
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

let isRefreshing = false;
let refreshPromise: Promise<any> | null = null;

export async function refreshAccessToken(token: any) {
  console.log('refresh token in process');
  // console.log('access token: ' + token.tokenAccess);
  // console.log('refresh token: ' + token.refreshToken);

  if (isRefreshing) {
    console.log('Refresh token is currently running, skip refresh');
    return refreshPromise;
  }

  console.log('Processing the refresh token');

  const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
  try {
    const url = baseUrl + '/token-refresh';
    const tokenAccess = token.tokenAccess;
    console.log('Token sent for refresh:', tokenAccess);

    const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenAccess}`,
      },
    };

    isRefreshing = true; // Set flag to true to prevent double refresh token

    // Start the refresh process and save to refreshPromise so other requests can wait
    refreshPromise = axios.get(url, config)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          // console.log('Successfully got a new token:', res.data.new_token.token);

          // Reset flag after refresh is complete
          isRefreshing = false;
          refreshPromise = null;

          // Return the new token
          return {
            ...token,
            tokenAccess: res.data.new_token.token,
            expires_in: Date.now() + 120 * 1000, // Update token expiration time
            refreshToken: res.data.new_token.token ?? token.refreshToken, // Use new refresh token if available
          };
        } else {
          console.log('Failed to get new token:', res.status, res.data);
          throw new Error('Failed to refresh token');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error refreshing token:');
        // console.error('Error refreshing token:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);

        isRefreshing = false; // Reset flag when error occurs
        refreshPromise = null;

        // Return token with error
        return {
          ...token,
          error: 'RefreshAccessTokenError',
        };
      })

    return refreshPromise;
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('Failed to get new token, catch error:', error.message);

    isRefreshing = false;
    refreshPromise = null;

    return {
      ...token,
      error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
    };
  }
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    // maxAge: 120,
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email / Phone Number", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const payload = {
          user: {
            email_phone: credentials!.email,
            password: credentials!.password
          }
        }
        const res = await AuthService.handleLogin(payload);
        if (res.status === 200) {
          const user = {
            id: res.data.data.user_id,
            role: res.data.data.user_type,
            tokenAccess: res.data.data.access_token,
            // expires_in: res.data.data.expires_in,
            expires_in: Date.now() + 120 * 1000, // hardcoded for access token to be 2 minutes for now
            dataUser: res.data.data.user,
          }
          console.log('this is user', user)
          return user;
        } else {
          return null
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, user, trigger, session }: any) {

      // This will be for updating profile
      if (trigger === 'update') {
        token.dataUser = session.user.dataUser;
      }

      if (account && user) {
        if (account?.provider === 'credentials') {
          token.id = user.id;
          token.role = user.role;
          token.tokenAccess = user.tokenAccess;
          token.expires_in = user.expires_in;
          token.dataUser = user.dataUser;
          token.refreshToken = user.tokenAccess;
        }
      }
      console.log('this is current token', token.tokenAccess)
      console.log(token.expires_in)
      console.log('this is current time', Date.now())
      const bufferTime = 60 * 1000; // 60 seconds

      // Check if token is about to expire (less than bufferTime)
      if (Date.now() < token.expires_in) {
        console.log('token')
        return token; // Token is still valid, no need to refresh


      }



      if (token.error === "RefreshAccessTokenError") {
        console.log("Token refresh already failed, not trying again.");
        return token;
      }

      console.log('Token before update:', token.tokenAccess);
      const refreshedToken = await refreshAccessToken(token);
      console.log('Token after update on refresh token:', refreshedToken.tokenAccess);
      console.log('Token after update on token:', token.tokenAccess);
      if (refreshedToken.error) {
        // If refresh fails, mark token with error to not try again
        token.error = refreshedToken.error;
      }

      // return refreshAccessToken(token);
      return refreshedToken;
    },

    async session({ session, token }: any) {

      if (token) {
        // session.user.dataUser = token.dataUser;
        // session.user.role = token.role;
        // session.accessToken = token.tokenAccess;
        // session.error = token.error;

        if ("dataUser" in token) {
          session.user.dataUser = token.dataUser;

        }
        if ("role" in token) {
          session.user.role = token.role;
        }
        if ("tokenAccess" in token) {
          session.user.name = token.tokenAccess; 
        }
        if ("expires_in" in token) {
          session.user.expires_in = token.expires_in;
        }
        if (token) {
          session.accessToken = token.tokenAccess as string}
      }
      session.error = token.error
      return session
    }
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
}

This setup aims to handle token refreshes efficiently. However, I'm encountering issues when attempting to refresh tokens after users have navigated away from and returned to the page. The refresh operation either doesn't trigger or fails, suggesting potential problems with state management or lifecycle events.
Questions:
How can I ensure that token refreshes are handled consistently, even when users return after some time?
Are there specific considerations or best practices with NextAuth that I should follow to improve the reliability of token refresh operations?
